# How to add standrad deviation and moving average

Tags: matlab

What I want to is:
I got folder with 32 `txt` files and 1 `excle` file, each file contain some data in two columns: time, level.

I already managed to pull the data from the folder and open each file in `Matlab` and get the data from it. What I need to do is create plot for each data file.
each of the 32 plots should have:

1. Change in average over time
2. Standard deviation

With both of this things I am straggling can't make it work.
also I need to make another plot this time the plot should have the average over each minute from all the 32 files.

here is my code until now:

```
clc,clear;
myDir = 'my path';
dirInfo = dir([myDir,'*.txt']);
filenames = {dirInfo.name};
N = numel(filenames);
data=cell(N,1); 
for i=1:N
    fid = fopen([myDir,filenames{i}] );
    data{i} = textscan(fid,'%f %f','headerlines',2);
    fclose(fid);
    temp1=data{i,1};
    time=temp1{1};
    level=temp1{2};
    Average(i)=mean(level(1:find(time>60)));
    AverageVec=ones(length(time),1).*Average(i);
    Standard=std(level);
    figure(i);
    plot(time,level);
    xlim([0 60]);
    hold on
    plot(time, AverageVec);
    hold on
    plot(time, Standard);
    legend('Level','Average','Standard Deviation')
end
```

the main problam with this code is that i get only average over all the 60 sec not moving average, and the standard deviation returns nothing.

few things you need to know:

- *temp1 is 1x2 cell
- *time and level are 22973x1 double.

Comment: `Standard=std(level);` 'returns nothing' , is it empty, nan, what does it return? Maybe have a look at `movmean` https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmean.html

Comment: to calc the moving avg use `conv(vec,ones(n,1)./n,'same')`. where `n` is the window size

Comment: @bla: why do you prefer this over `movmean`? Compare: `a=rand(1,1E3);b=movmean(a,100);c=conv(a,ones(100,1)./100,'same');plot(1:1E3,b,'b',1:1E3,c,'r')` the conv method has edge effects

Comment: @Gelliant: ty for the answer gelliant and bla.
about the movmean its an 2018 version func so i cant use it, i have matlab2015.
about conv(vec,ones(n,1)./n,'same') i tried this but im not sure what it is calculating.. look at the photo it doesnt look like standard deviation.
https://imgur.com/a/nFf3NOZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apperently you need an alternative to movmean and movstd since they where introduced in 2016a. I combined the suggestion from @bla with two loops that correct for the edge effects.

```
function [movmean,movstd] = moving_ms(vec,k)
if mod(k,2)==0,k=k+1;end
L = length(vec);
movmean=conv(vec,ones(k,1)./k,'same');
% correct edges
n=(k-1)/2;
movmean(1) = mean(vec(1:n+1));
N=n;
for ct = 2:n
    movmean(ct) = movmean(ct-1) + (vec(ct+n) - movmean(ct-1))/N;
    N=N+1;
end
movmean(L) = mean(vec((L-n):L));
N=n;
for ct = (L-1):-1:(L-n)
    movmean(ct) = movmean(ct+1) + (vec(ct-n) - movmean(ct+1))/N;
    N=N+1;
end

%mov variance
movstd = nan(size(vec));
for ct = 1:n
    movstd(ct) = sum((vec(1:n+ct)-movmean(ct)).^2);
    movstd(ct) = movstd(ct)/(n+ct-1);
end
for ct = n+1:(L-n)
    movstd(ct) = sum((vec((ct-n):(ct+n))-movmean(ct)).^2);
    movstd(ct) = movstd(ct)/(k-1);
end
for ct = (L-n):L
    movstd(ct) = sum((vec((ct-n):L)-movmean(ct)).^2);
    movstd(ct) = movstd(ct)/(L-ct+n);
end
movstd=sqrt(movstd);
```

Someone with matlab >=2016a can compare them using:

```
v=rand(1,1E3);m1 = movmean(v,101);s1=movstd(v,101);
[m2,s2] = moving_ms(v,101);
x=1:1E3;figure(1);clf;
subplot(1,2,1);plot(x,m1,x,m2);
subplot(1,2,2);plot(x,s1,x,s2);
```

It should show a single red line since the blue line is overlapped.